# Java EE record product impressions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Part of my project requires that we maintain stats of our customers products. More or less we want to show our customers how often their products has been viewed on the site

Therefore we want to create some form of Product Impressions Counter. I do not just mean a counter when we land on the specific product page, but when the product appears in search results and in our product directory lists.

I was thinking that after calling the DB I would extract the specific product ids and pass them to a service that will then inserted then into the stats tables. Or another is using some form of singleton buffer writer which writes to the DB after it reaches a certains size?

Has anyone ever encountered this in there projects and have any ideas that they would like to share?

And / or does anyone know of any framework or tools that could aid this development?

Any input would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't have performance problems, do not over-engineer your design. On the other hand, depending on how big the site is, it seem that you **are** going to have performance problems due to huge amount of writes.

I think real time updates will have a huge performance impact. Also it is very likely that you will update the same data multiple times in short period of time. Another thing is that, although interesting, storing this statistics is not mission-cricital and it shouldn't affect normal system work. Final thought: inconsistencies and minor inaccuracy is IMHO acceptable in this use case.

Taking all this into account I would temporarily hold the statistics in memory and flush them periodically as you've suggested. This has the additional benefit of merging events for the same product - if between two flushed some product was visited 10 times, you will only perform one update, not 10.

Technically, you can use **properly synchronized** singleton with background thread (a lot of handcrafting) or some intelligent cache with write-behind technology.

Comment: Tomasz, thanks for you input, this has definately cleared up some of my doubts. Clearly the real time solutions is not viable due to the performace impacts.